# How can I merge all the changes from 1 branch to another

Tags: git

In git, what is the easiest way for me to merge all changes (multiple commits) from 1 branch to another branch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git checkout branchA
git merge -Xtheirs branchB
```

(For git1.7.1+)

Other older alternatives are presented in "[`git merge -s ours`, what about “`their`”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173919/git-merge-s-ours-what-about-their)"